# FFT not showing any dominant frequencies

Tags: scipy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to perform an FFT from time series data of DC motor current from "F.A.I.R. open dataset of brushed DC motor faults for testing of AI algorithms". However, the result does not show any dominant frequency bands. It just resembles broadband noise. The first image is a zoomed in snap shot of the time series data (the entire series is over 100,000 data points), after the DC portion has been substracted.

[Timeseries graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wofk.jpg)

The second image is the fft graph and my code is below. The time period is not yet set correctly but this does not effect the form of the data, only the frequency values assigned to it.

[FFT graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XfvN.jpg)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
filename = "MOTOR-DC_2020_12_02_17_59_47_Analogico.hdf5"
#MOTOR-DC_2020_12_02_17_59_47_Analogico.hdf5
#MOTOR-DC_2020_12_02_17_30_42_Analogico.hdf5
with h5py.File(filename, "r") as f:
# List all groups
print("Keys: %s" % f.keys())
a_group_key = list(f.keys())[0]

# Get the data
data = list(f[a_group_key])
    
vibration =[(data[i][0]) for i in range(0,len(data))]   
current =[(data[i][1]) for i in range(0,len(data))]
voltage=current =[(data[i][2]) for i in range(0,len(data))]
x=list(range(0,len(vibration)))

from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import numpy as np
# Number of sample points
N = len(data)#600
# sample spacing
T = 0.0001
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)
y = current
y_mean=np.mean(y)
y_med=np.median(y)
print('Mean',y_mean,'Median=',y_med)

for i in range(0,len(y)):
     y[i]=y[i]-y_mean

#plt.plot(x,current)    
yf = fft(y)
xf = fftfreq(n=N, d=T)[:N//2]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: One value in the FFT is much bigger than all the other ones.  Why do you say it isn't a dominant frequency?

Comment: I suggest you start with a known input signal say a 1kHz tone then feed this into your FFT call to confirm you are seeing this frequency

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try

```py
yf = fft(y)
xf = fftfreq(N)
xf[np.argmax(np.abs(yf))]
```

This will give you the normalized frequency of the most prominent harmonic.

You can then multiply it by the sampling frequency to get the actual frequency.

Comment: Thank you, I am just very surprised as for such a periodic waveform I would have expected a much larger amplitude for the strongest frequency and a number of harmonics that are significantly stronger than the 'background'. The unit waveform reminds me a little of a graph of y=-x^**3. I will create such a waveform and play with it (add noise, contract or expand the waveform) as a learning exercise.

Comment: Even though your signal is periodic it is not harmonic. Also you signal has some sudden jumps, it is not a signal that Fourier transform is good at approximating. To give you some better impression of what the Fourier transform can do, take the [Sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) the energy in the harmonics is infinitely more than the energy in the fundamental (but still the fundamental is the highest energy harmonic).